# Are There Inflection Points In A Function With No Critical Points?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function, defined as:

$f(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2-25}$

It has been determined to have no critical points since the x-values would be the same as the vertical asymptotes.

I have also determined that the function is always decreasing for the entire domain of the function. Domain is $\{x| x \ne \pm 5, x\in R\}$

With this information, can I conclude there are no inflection points and no concavity?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jvlhn7hugx

Comment: The domain can't be the whole of $\Bbb R$, because the function is undefined at $x=\pm 5$.

Answer (score 2):

A monotonic function can have intervals of concavity bound by points of inflection.

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{2x}{x^2-25}\\
f'(x)&=\frac{-2x^2-50}{(x^2-25)^2}=-2\left(\frac{x^2+25}{(x^2-25)^2}\right)\\
f''(x)&=-2\left(\frac{2x(x^2-25)-2(2x)(x^2+25)}{(x^2-25)^3}\right)\\
&=-2\left(\frac{2x^3-50x-4x^3-100x}{(x^2-25)^3}\right)\\
&=4x\left(\frac{x^2+75}{(x^2-25)^3}\right)
\end{align}

By inspection, there is a point of inflection at $(0,0)$.

---

Another way to see that there *must* be a point of inflection is to recognize that $f(x)$ is odd.  By the nature of rotational symmetry, concave up intervals have their counterpart concave down intervals.

Answer (score 0):

if your domain is restricted, and you have determined the function is decreasing and any critical points would have been a vertical asymptote, then it will surely have no inflection points. Specifying your domain here would be helpful for the reader to help you.

Comment: I should have specified the domain in the question. I did above now. It's all values of x $\{x\in R\}$.